# No monetdbd installed on linux64 (opensuse 12.2)

Tags: software-installation, database

I have installed `monetdb` from `MonetDB-11.15.7.zip` on a linux64 box following the instruction in the `HowToStart.rst` file. The Download is available [here](http://dev.monetdb.org/downloads/sources/Latest/MonetDB-11.15.7.zip).

According to the Monetdb's quick start page I should be able to run (note monetdb **is not** monetdbd)

```
shell> monetdbd create /path/to/mydbfarm
```

but there's no **`monetdbd`** installed on my system according to

```
find / -iname "*monetdbd"
```

Instead **`monetdb`** and `mclient` are installed, but I got respectively

```
monetdb status
> monetdb: cannot find a control socket, use -h and/or -p

mclient
> could not connect to localhost:50000: Connection refused
```

What has gone wrong with my installation?

**SOLVED**

Actually I should have payed attention to the `./configure` output

```
./configure ...

* Enabled/disabled components:
    gdk is enabled
    monetdb5 is enabled
    sql is enabled
    jaql is enabled
    geom is enabled
    fits is enabled
    rdf is disabled (by default)
    datacell is disabled (by default)
    odbc is enabled
    jdbc is enabled
    control is enabled
    testing is enabled
```

Most of the needed library were missing when I first installed it.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but did you compile and install?

Comment: yes, as specified in the HowToStart.rst file. Actually there was a typo in the title, it's the monetdbd (not monetdb) that is missing

Comment: So you did run a `make install` I think is what @Mat eluding to? I just ran the compile and I see a monetdbd here: `./tools/merovingian/daemon/monetdbd`. I didn't do the `make install` yet.

Comment: Thanks for help! I haven't payed attention to ./configure output. Actually I needed to install a few libraries to get all the functionalities. I update the thread accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue may have something to do with your environment setup. Do you have the directory /usr/local/bin on your $PATH?

```
printenv PATH | grep "/usr/local/bin"
```

This should return $PATH with that directory within it. If not then you'll not be able to run monetdbd without giving it the fully qualified path to the executable:

```
/usr/local/bin/monetdbd
```

I just downloaded, configured, and made MonetDB and found the various executables you mentioned.

#### my installation

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/monetdb* /usr/local/bin/mclient
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 261422 May  1 05:10 /usr/local/bin/mclient
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 198612 May  1 05:10 /usr/local/bin/monetdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 364977 May  1 05:10 /usr/local/bin/monetdbd
```

Also when running the `make install` step you have to run it using `sudo`.